# How to call actuator health endpoint from screwdriver yml file to check container health?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, screwdriver-cd

I am having a gradle based spring boot project with screwdriver as CI/CD tool. The CI jobs are specified using templates. I have the requirement of testing the docker container health while PR build. I am thinking of following approach :

1. Build the docker image
2. Run the docker container on build server
3. Calling the actuator health endpoint
4. Stopping the container
5. Return response based on step 3 result

With this approach, I am trying to figure out if there is a way through which I can actually catch the response of api call and then act accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515333/how-to-do-a-health-check-of-a-spring-boot-application-running-in-a-docker-contai

Comment: @yassiraitelaizzi thanks for the link. I am actually facing issue with providing healthcheck as mentioned above with com.bmuschko.docker-spring-boot-application plugin being used in gradle. Please help. Thanks in advance.